# String comparison doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell

For some reason this script prints "string are equal"

```
#!/bin/bash
A='foo'
B='bar'

if [ $A=$B ];
then
  echo 'strings are equal' 
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to leave a space around the equal sign:

```
if [ "$A" = "$B" ];
then
  echo 'strings are equal' 
fi
```

*Edit:* Please notice also the quotation marks around the variables.  Without them you will get into trouble if one of them is empty.

Otherwise the test is interpreted as *test if the string "foo=bar" has a length>0*.
See `man test`:

```
   ...
   STRING equivalent to -n STRING
   -n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero
   ...
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you did the right thing and added quotes around the variables.  If you're comparing strings without quotes and one is empty, your script will exit due to a malformed test.

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, you are right. I should have mentioned that fact.

Answer (score 7):

You're supposed to have spaces around the equals character:

```
if [ $A = $B ];
       ^ ^
      There
```

Also, you ought to quote the variables, like this:

```
if [ "$A" = "$B" ];
```